# How to access a wireless IP CAM from one Wireless network to another Wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Recently I got a **Apexis IP Wireless camera** and I have configured it to my Belkin Router. All users who is connected to this Router able to access this camera with my configured IP and port (192.168.2.5:81).

But I have another Router and some other computers are connected to this Router(2), but they are not able to access this IP Camera with this IP and port.

Yes, I configured my Belkin Router to forward this for from **Firewall >> Virtual Server**.
Now please help to figure it out, how to access this CAM from different Router network's computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How are the two routers connected? 
Is the internal address for the cam 192.168.2.5 and port 81? 
If Router2 is on an "external" network from Router1 (Connection coming in from the WAN port?) you need to connect to Router1's address and not the camera. If Router1 is serving IP-addresses on DHCP to your local devices at 192.168.2.* and got the external IP 10.10.10.1 (just an example), you got to connect to 10.10.10.1:81 from all the computers that are connected to Router2.

Followup could be: what ip do the computers at Router2 have? Is it the same network/subnet? How does the traffic flow to Router1?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These two routes are not connected each other. Camera is on Router 1 (192.168.2.xxx). Network for Router 2 is 192.168.1.xxx. Both routers are connected to Internet though two different modem.
I just wanna access this Camera from a PC which is connected to Router 2.

Comment: If it's via the internet, you have to find the external IP of your router1. By browsing from a computer on the same network (Router1) go to whatismyip.com and take a note of that address. If everything is correctly set up, you should be able to use that address from site2 (pc connected to Router2) + port number: http to external.ip.router.1:81

Comment: Thank you very much again. May be I understood your answer. So I need to bridge my two router first? I told you before there are two different Internet modem connected with these two routers. Is it possible to connect these two routers through Wireless? Or it would be great if I don't need to connect these two router each other but only configuring one.

Comment: See my comment regarding connecting these two networks directly... another router would be necessary.

Comment: @MahbubRony If they are connected via internet - that is enough. Just use the -externa- address, and not the local one. From behind Router2, do NOT use 192.168.2.5, but the external one for that internet access. (Which I described how to aquire from whatsmyip.com).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a free video streaming service like ustream.tv, which you would send one live stream to their servers, that can then be viewed by several web clients, with no need for them to connect to (or use the resources of...) your private network.  It would be very difficult to interconnect two LANs without DHCP problems with only two small office/home office routers.  It's possible with a 3rd router that is set up with static IPs, say its WAN port with 192.168.2.254/255.255.255.0 and its LAN interface 192.168.1.254/255.255.255.0, with its NAT feature turned off, as well.  Then, from your camera host, you would configure a route to 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 via 192.168.2.254, and from any host on the other network that wanted to reach the camera, a static route 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 via 192.168.1.254.

However, without another router to isolate the two LANs, any attempt to inter-connect them will result in polluting your DHCP pools.